# Workflow failed to run after pause - SP2010

Tags: workflow, powershell

I am trying to fix a paused workflow issue following this KB Article from Microsoft.
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2674684

However, when I try to run the powershell command I get this error as shown below

```
PS C:\Users\admin> $webapp = Get-SPWebApplication -identity http://testportal:300

PS C:\Users\admin> $webapp.UpdateWorkflowConfigurationSetttings()

Method invocation failed because [Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPWebAppl
ication] doesn't contain a method named 'UpdateWorkflowConfigurationSetttings.
At line:1 char:45
+ $webapp.UpdateWorkflowConfigurationSetttings <<<< ()
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (UpdateWorkflowConfigurationSe
   tttings:String) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : MethodNotFound
```

Powershell says SPWebapplication does not contain the method Updateworkflowconfigurationsettings however as per [MSDN SDK reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.administration.spwebapplication.updateworkflowconfigurationsettings.aspx) , this method exists.

Please suggest what am I missing here.

Comment: You've specified Settttttings with a triple t

Comment: Jakobsen, nice catch! :)

Comment: Thanks Per ! That was really a catch. I have sent a feedback to Microsoft on the same KB Article so that it saves poor souls like me :).

Comment: It is 2015 and the mentioned MSDN still contains the same typo.

Comment: Also, may I know is above command required to be ran regularly to keep the workflow configuration up-to-date in Database?

Comment: method named 'UpdateWorkflowConfigurationSetttings'
change Se**ttt**ings to Se**tt**ings

Comment: The same "triple t" shows up at https://community.nintex.com/message/23848#23848 so Nintex Workflow people, take note. I just hit this snag myself.

Answer (score 1):

replace `$webapp.UpdateWorkflowConfigurationSetttings()`

with

```
$webapp.UpdateWorkflowConfigurationSettings()
```

as it have extra 't' in it, It is a typo in MSDN